# how to solve MongoServerSelectionError?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRvO2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVmjD.png)

I am trying to link node.js and mongodb. but when I write code to find info from the database it shows an error called MongoServerSelectionError. My database and everything is currect but still it is not working. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.